# Where is the Exception Assistant in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2013

I just started using VS2013 Express for Windows, but I'm more used to VS2008.

When an exception is thrown in my program, I see the following window:
[image: VS2013 Exception Message]

I get no more information.  If I click break, I have no way to even find out what type of exception was thrown again.  In older versions, I was able to click "Details" and open a property window.  At least, if I closed it, I was able to open the exception details again by hilighting the problem line while the execution was still paused.

Is there any way to get the old functionality, or at least an equivalent?  This makes it much harder to debug without the full information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a known problem in 2012/2013 (Express edition):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806898/the-exception-assistant-is-missing-again-in-2013

Good luck!

Comment: The DLL is mine.  There is a Try/Catch already that logs and re-throws the exception for the higher library to handle.  The problem is that it's a TypeInitializationException, which means I really need the InnerException property for it to be useful.  Breaking the code and adding a watch to the 'Exception e' variable returns "The name 'e' doesn't exist in the current context" which is incredible since the break line reads "throw e;" Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Also, my real problem is that I can't for the life of me get the Exception Assistant to show.  That would solve this issue if it would just show up.

Comment: Looks like a known problem in Express:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806898/the-exception-assistant-is-missing-again-in-2013.  I use Ultimate and have access to the Exception Assistant.

Comment: Yup, you're right.  Well, that's the third major problem I've had with Windows Store development.  Time to abandon for more friendly platforms.  It's too bad really; Microsoft used to be so dev friendly.

Comment: Developers, developers, developers, developers.  Developers...sorry, I couldn't help myself.